# WooCommercec Advanced Shipping Method not accurate

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Im using WooCommerce Advance Shipping Plugin on eCommerce Website.

I have set shipping method on each product category
   eg. (cat: mobile shipping cost $20, cat: accessories shipping cost $5 etc)

When client ordering one specific product till that working fine as condition. But not getting accurate result in multiple categories product in chart.

**Single Product:**

Mobile cost: $500

shipping cost $20

*Total: $520*

---

**Multiple product with Multiple Category**

Mobile cost: $500

Shipping cost $20

Mobile Cover: $50

Shipping Cover: $10

*Total: $580*

here im getting wrong result, plugin is not counting shipping cost and directly showing $550.

Help will be very appreciate.

Comment: Feel free to reach out here to get support: http://jeroensormani.com/woocommerce-advanced-shipping/support/ ;-)

Comment: bro its not works on different product category.

Comment: You probably want to combine shipping rates, right? This doc will explain things: http://docs.shopplugins.com/article/39-combine-shipping-rates